# visualization of 3D probability flow

Tags: matlab, visualization, stochastic, probability

I have a master equation for $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$, with $N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+$ all discrete. The numerical integration is done by this Matlab [program](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7383429/Archive.zip) using Euler's method. Despite the crude Euler's method, the results from numerical integration are in agreement with the simulation, so the correctness of the program is not the focus.

I want to see how $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$ evolves over time. Since $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$ has 3 more coordinates in addition to time, it is really hard to visualize the changes. Ideally, I want to have something like

[image]

But I cannot find any function in Matlab that can does something similar. The closest thing I can find is Matlab's `contourslice` function.

By running the Matlab program mentioned above with

```
ABC_driver(0.5,100,20,200,10,true);
```

you will get something like the following:

[image]

[image]

You can guess what happens to $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$, but it is nowhere as obvious as the atomic orbital graph.

My question is, how can I plot $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$ in way similar to the atomic orbital density plot? Or can anyone suggest better way to visualize the time evolution of $P(N_A^+,N_B^+,N_C^+,t)$?

Comment: Cool plot!  Where did that come from?

Comment: @meawoppl, the upper plot comes from [here](http://blog.nag.com/2010/12/paraview-vtk-files-and-endianness.html), the lower 6 plots are from `contourslice` in Matlab.

Comment: dead link, fixed one [here](https://www.nag.com/content/paraview-vtk-files-and-endianness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice volume rendering toolbox for MATLAB:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2

I think you could tweak it for your purposes.

Comment: looks very useful!

Comment: I would encourage those in Python land with the same questions to checkout out mayavi2:
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/

Answer (score 4):

Programs like Visit and Paraview can do "volume rendering", which is what you show in your figure. You just need to export the data you have in a format that either of these programs can read.