# Recreating this 3D density plot in ParaView

Tags: visualization, paraview

I want to do somethings similar to the plot found at the bottom of [this](http://blog.nag.com/2010/12/paraview-vtk-files-and-endianness.html) blogpost, which I found via [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10910/visualization-of-3d-probability-flow) post in ParaView, which seems to have been the original Application used to generate the plot.

I have a `.csv`-file containing data points of the form $(x, y, z, a)$ where $a$ ranges from 0 to 1 and represents gives the probability density - or "fog" density that should be plottet.

My question is, how to plot this datafile/which ParaView filters to use to create this plot.

Comment: And what is your question? How to do the plot or how to create the input file?

Comment: @nicoguaro I already have the input file, I just can't figure out how to plot it.

Comment: You need more than just data points to use volume rendering.

Comment: @nicoguaro Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Yes, it is basically the answer of Biswajit Banerjee. You need to have a function define over your domain. For that you need a mesh, a regular mesh is the best option for volume rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to interpolate the points to a 3D grid (a regular grid will do) and then do the volume rendering.  See https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=Volume_Rendering for some examples.